# How to order combinations with repetition spatially

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Sorry for choosing a title that isn't really expressive but I couldn't come up with anything better.

I'm looking for an **algorithmic** way to find combinations with repetition and order them spatially in the following way:

order 2 (2x2):

```
AA   AB 
AD AC/BD
```

order 4 (4x4):

```
AAAA    AAAB     AABB    ABBB
AAAD AAAC/AABD AABC/ABBD ABBC
AADD AACD/ABDC ABCD/AACC ABCC
ADDD    ACDD     ACCD    ACCC
```

Especially those two-option fields (e.g. AAAC/AABD) are giving me headaches. The combinations will be used to compute correlations between real pixels. I.e. for instance the combination AA would be the autocorrelation of A while AB would be the cross correlation of A and B.

This scheme is required for a microscopy algorithm I'm currently trying to implement (see the section on cross cumulants):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-resolution_optical_fluctuation_imaging

On top of that, I also need to do this in a most efficient manner as possible as I would typically have to perform the operation on thousands of images with each being at least 512x512 (I'm doing this in CUDA). EDIT: well I just realized that high efficiency is not really required as the pattern won't change once an order has been chosen.

This image may help:

[image]

Comment: Providing a formal goal may help. It's hard to guess why the strings are ordered this way.

Comment: @Gassa - if I got it right, it is a procedure to rise resolution using temporal data - real pixels being the original ones and the virtual pixels being the calculated ones (unless he is trying to apply this in somewhere else, in which case the formal goal is God knows what)

Comment: @john-smith Look at the references- few of the cited articles from Wikipedia are available through Google Scholar, so you can start from there

Comment: @Vairis, thanks for clarifying. I'm intending to apply the algorithm for the problem it was invented for. I've read through the papers that I could find but so far I haven't seen a description of how the combinations were assigned to the virtual pixels. What's quite deceiving about this problem is that it's rather trivial to find the combinations themselves but not as easy to assign a particular combination (or several) to a particular pixel.

Comment: @JohnSmith - in which language are you going to implement it?

Comment: @Vairis - I'm using CUDA, so it will be C/C++. However, I just realized that efficiency is not a requirement as it is sufficient to determine the pattern just once before I start running through the images.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I found a MATLAB toolbox for Balanced SOFI analysis (under GNU public license) on this page: http://documents.epfl.ch/users/l/le/leuteneg/www/BalancedSOFI/index.html -- even if you can't use MATLAB code, it may be possible to convert it to your programming language.

---

Of the eight references of the Wikipedia article, some are behind paywalls, but figures (or thumbnails of them) freely viewable for all but t he two oldest articles.  Only one article gives free access to a figure resembling the one from Wikipedia (with AAAB, AABB, etc.):

http://www.opticsinfobase.org/boe/abstract.cfm?uri=boe-2-3-408

If I were in your position, I would attempt to contact the authors of that paper directly and ask them what the figure means, because I did not see how they decided to use these combinations.  Within the 3x3 set of interpolated pixels that are bounded symmetrically by pixes A, B, C, D at their four corners, why is A the only letter that is required to occur in every single combination?  If I understand what the letters signify (relative weightings of the real pixels in each interpolated pixel's value), then the pixel on the intersection of the diagonals, labeled ABCD AACC, gives twice as much weight to A and C as to B and D; in fact, on average that entire 3x3 block of pixels gives A and C twice as much weight as B and D.  That does not seem consistent with the underlying symmetries of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that code was actually available. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The mathematics in the wiki link you provided (about Super-resolution optical fluctuation imaging) may require quite a bit of study for me to understand, but I observe at least one possible way to think of diagram A:

I think of `A` as an anchor from which vectors extend to `B`, `C`, and `D`. The direct vectors are probably fairly obvious - as we move from `A` directly toward `D`, the `D`s accumulate (i.e., AAAD, AADD, ADDD); as with `A` to `B` and `A` to `C`.

I see the middle combinations as vectors extending from the border either horizontally or vertically. For example, going down from AAAB, we add one `D`, then another; going to the right from AADD, we add one `C`, then reach the middle, ABCD.

I think any one combination in the diagram is sorted alphabetically, which would account for the apparent discrepancy in the positions of some accumulations, for example, the position of the accumulating `C` when moving from ADDD to ACCC, compared with the position of the accumulating `C' when moving from ABBB to ACCC.